# When I hover over variables in ts file I don't see a comment with their types

Tags: typescript

I started to learn TypeScript and I have this problem when I hover on the variable name: it doesn't show me a comment with the TypeScript type.

I tried to look online, maybe it is because of some extension, I have to mention that it worked before until I opened a new file:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share us more information. Which IDE do you use? Are there any Plugins installed?

Answer (score 1):

as seen in your screenshot, you actually can see the type.
`let firstname: 'Jenny';` creates an empty mutable variable that can only store a string "Jenny". You cannot assign any other string to it. The type here is literally `string with value "Jenny" in it` although the value is not yet assigned.

I imagine that you meant to write `let firstname = 'Jenny'`. That will create a variable of type 'string' which contains the value "Jenny" and if you hover over that, you will indeed see type "string".

You can also write `let firstname = 'Jenny' as const` which will create a variable with value "Jenny" that can only ever store the value "Jenny" (the type is `string with value "Jenny" in it`)

Comment: You can ask your (now deleted) question here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/